# Node.js Performance Varies with Different File Formats?

Tags: node.js, png, buffer, jpeg

Our company has written a server in Node.js that primarily handles dynamic content, but occasionally we need to serve files in various formats, including images. It works fine for the most part, but the performance varies wildly depending on the file format. The files are just stored on disk, we are not doing any processing of the images or other files in Node.

For example, we tested several JPG, PNG, PDF, and EXE files and there appeared to be something with Node that affected the different formats. PNG files were the worst, JPG and EXE seemed to be the best. File size didn't seem to be an issue (JPG image much larger than the PNG would transfer faster), and unless my understanding is incorrect the size shouldn't have been a factor since they are all stored in a Buffer object.

The original server uses Express, so we wanted to make sure that wasn't somehow interfering and wrote this small bare-bones file server as a test. It was designed to rule out disk access times by only loading the file once at start-up (negligible difference, to say the least). Using Apache Benchmark, we found that the problem still exists in such a bare-bones implementation. We have been developing primarily on Windows, but the same results were seen on Ubuntu. We tested all cases without a Content-type header (and thus the mime lookup call), spoofing the mime type (so a PNG would have an "image/jpeg" header and vice versa), and changing the file extensions, all of which had no noticeable impact. Here is the test server:

```
var fs = require("fs"),
  http = require("http"),
  filePath = process.argv[2];
  fileData = fs.readFileSync(filePath),
  mimeType = require("mime").lookup(filePath);

var server = http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, { "Content-type": mimeType });
  res.end(fileData);
});

server.listen(3000);
console.log("File server started. Serving: " + filePath);

process.on("uncaughtException", function (err) {
  console.log("Caught exception: " + err.stack);
});
```

Is there something we are missing here? We can't seem to find any documentation or explanation for this issue. We are not interested in changing to a different server platform, we just want files to transfer at the same rate regardless of format. Why are some file formats taking so much longer to transfer than others?

The following two test results are provided for reference, the test was run multiple times and results were typically in this range.

```
ab -n 1000 -c 100 http://127.0.0.1:3000/
```

### JPEG, 440KB

```
Concurrency Level:      100
Time taken for tests:   4.430 seconds
Complete requests:      1000
Failed requests:        0
Write errors:           0
Total transferred:      497711000 bytes
HTML transferred:       497610000 bytes
Requests per second:    225.73 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       443.009 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       4.430 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          109714.73 [Kbytes/sec] received
```

### PNG, 485KB

```
Concurrency Level:      100
Time taken for tests:   75.969 seconds
Complete requests:      1000
Failed requests:        0
Write errors:           0
Total transferred:      451543000 bytes
HTML transferred:       451443000 bytes
Requests per second:    13.16 [#/sec] (mean)
Time per request:       7596.900 [ms] (mean)
Time per request:       75.969 [ms] (mean, across all concurrent requests)
Transfer rate:          5804.47 [Kbytes/sec] received
```

EDIT: It appears that Symantec Endpoint Protection was the culprit, even though we thought it wouldn't affect the results on the Ubuntu test (it wasn't on that machine). The files transfer correctly now.

Comment: Just used a 440KB PNG file and a 480KB JPG, `ab -n 5000 -c 50 http://127.0.0.1:3000/` as command line (as I couldn't get `-c 100` to work). Results were essentially the same for the two files.

Comment: 1) You should probably set the content length header to the length of the buffer. 2) Which version of node are you using? (this is important).

Comment: @MattEsch
1) I'll look into that, but I don't understand how that would affect the transfer rates of two files nearly the same size.
2) We have been using v0.10.20 typically. I did test with v0.10.22 and a compiled build of v0.11.9 from the GitHub repository, all on Windows 7 x64. The other tests were performed on Ubuntu 12.10 with whatever apt-get had as of three days ago, probably v0.10.22.

Comment: Did u done both test on the same machine with same version of nodejs?Your code seems fine and this works fine with node version 0.8.21 with widows 32 bit pc

Comment: I've ran the tests multiple times on each machine on each version of Node.js mentioned previously. Tomorrow I will try an older version to see if it works any different.

Comment: I tried v0.8.21, no significant difference (about a second slower on the JPG test). Same for setting the Content-Length header.

Comment: I am curious as to what happens when you send the buffer of data on next tick? `process.nextTick(function () { res.end(fileData) });`

Comment: @dmecham create a github repo which reproduces this with the files / script & commands to run the tests. Then ask someone to reproduce it. If it can be reproduced then ask on IRC or open an issue on node

Comment: Now I have tested on my home machine, and despite having worse specs (lower memory, fewer cores) it performs better and the file format no longer makes a difference (at least between JPG and PNG). The only difference I can think of is that the work machines were all Intel-based (Core i7 for most, if it matters) and my home machine is an AMD Athlon II X3, but I fail to see why that would be the issue.
@Raynos I already provided the entirety of the code and the testing command in my original question. GitHub would be overkill. Any two similar-sized JPG and PNG images would do.

Comment: @dmecham the point of placing it on github is that a node core developer will do `git clone gh:dmecham/node-bug && npm run start` to reproduce your bug. Copying your source code & creating two images is far too much effort to try and chase down a phantom bug. Being able to run a single command to verify your bug means its more likely you will be helped

Comment: Tested it on machine ( MacOX Mavericks ) got the same results for both JPG and PNG Images

Comment: I'm fairly certain that the problem was Symantec Endpoint Protection. Not sure how it affected the Ubuntu test (it's only installed on the Windows machines) but completely disabling it fixed the issue. It appears that it scans compressed network streams similar to a scheduled disk scan, and PNG files use similar compression to zip files. That would also explain why some of the PDF files transferred more slowly, as they contained compressed images.